# Using mule magento connector in mule 3.2

Tags: magento, mule

I have tried to use the lastest version of magento connector on mule 3.2. However I keep getting this error:

SAXParseException: cos-all-limited.1.2: An all model group must appear in a particle with {min occurs} = {max occurs} = 1, and that particle must be part of a pair which constitutes the {content type} of a complex type definition.

I have googled it and I think the problem is a bug in mule's devkit. And I am getting it because the magento connector is built using the devkit. The bug apparently has been fixed according to this link:

https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-devkit/issues/10

Where can I download the fixed version of the devkit? and how do I install it in mule 3.2?

Cheers
Leo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug have been fixed indeed. If the Magento connector you're using has been compiled with a recent DevKit, things should be fine. Where did you get the Magento connector you're using? Have you tried building a fresh one from [source](https://github.com/mulesoft/magento-connector)?

DevKit can be found in MuleSoft Maven releases repository: https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/mule/tools/devkit

This said, you do not need to install DevKit it in Mule *per se*. DevKit is primarily used at compile time as a code generator for modules (like the Magento one). It may bring runtime dependencies but they'll be packaged with the module distribution archive (alongside the module Jar itself).

Comment: Hi David!! I have downloaded the current version of the connector and I have tried compiling it myself since I am trying to improve some functionality in the connector. However I keep getting that error when  mule tries to start the app. Everything seems fine with the connector's pom.xml. So i have no idea what could be the problem. Maybe another bug? Where should I report this?

Comment: Darn, that's annoying. Report the issue directly in GitHub, in the Magento project. Specify all versions you used, how you packaged your app and started Mule. Please link the issue here so we can follow up.

Comment: I have reported the issue. The link is https://github.com/mulesoft/magento-connector/issues/2